# Chrome console - what does this stuff that represents a Kendo UI widget actually mean?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kendo-ui, console, javascript-objects

So I'm using Kendo UI and attaching a widget. In the browser JavaScript console I can look up the object representing the widget:

```
$('#sidebar').data('kendoResponsivePanel')
```

and I see this in the console:

```
a.e…d.init {element: I.fn.init[1], _events: Object, options: Object, _guid: "_2d771e97-e660-4ee9-9141-8a9d9cc2e42e"}
```

followed by various properties of the object. What does this part actually mean? What is the a.e...d.init bit telling me? All I need is to know where to look for a reference, or some kind of pointer that gets me on the right track. I think I need to understand JavaScript prototyping also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies If if I don't understand your question entirely but  I believe that if you assign this:

```
$('#sidebar').data('kendoResponsivePanel')
```

into a variable and the variable is not undefined or null the widget is created.

```
var myWidget =  $('#sidebar').data('kendoResponsivePanel')

if(myWidget)
{
    // then it exists.
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok based on your comment and looking at this image:

[image]

I believe these are the build in (non "public" widget functionality) being exposed by Chrome.  The actual methods, fields and events which you should really then be interacting with are define din the API reference documentation for each particular widget type.  You can see the Kendo UI JS combobox ones here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox

I guess if you want a more detailed insight into it contacting Telerik directly may help.

Comment: Yes, sorry, bad title on the OP which I'll fix. You're right, and more specifically, what you then have is a reference to the widget and it's properties in the variable you've assigned. My question is that in the console when you check the value of that object, it shows an output that I don't fully understand, and I want to have command of the detail of what I'm seeing in the console

Comment: Yes that's a good summary of some of the detail. From what I've subsequently researched, the  n.e…d.init (e.g. a.e...d.init, o.e...d.init) may be referring to the prototype of the object, and the initial literal that appears in this (a, o, n) etc., is being dynamically assigned somewhere